# Can't reassign variable in CoffeeScript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I am new to CoffeeScript and try to write Angular controller. However I think I have a problem with variable scoping. My code is following:

```
app.controller 'IndexController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'Items', 'Snackbar', ($scope, Authentication, Items, Snackbar) ->
    activate = ->
        itemsSuccessFn = (data, status, headers, config) ->
            vm.items = data.data
            return

        itemsErrorFn = (data, status, headers, config) ->
            Snackbar.error data.error
            return

        Items().all().then itemsSuccessFn, itemsErrorFn
        return

    vm = this
    vm.items = []
    vm.isAuthenticated = Authentication.isAuthenticated()
    activate()
    return
]
```

The problem is with the items variable. When running an `itemsSuccessFn` in `activate` the variable is filled with data coming from the service. But in the main scope the variable is again empty. What am I doing wrong? How should I solve it?

If there is anything else concerning the code, that should be done better, please let me know, because as I mentioned I have just started learning.

Comment: What do you mean with `in the main scope the variable  is again empty`? Are you using the "controller as"-syntax? Example: `ng-controller="IndexController as vm"`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring a local variable, you can directly reference `$scope`.

```
app.controller 'IndexController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'Items', 'Snackbar', ($scope, Authentication, Items, Snackbar) ->
    activate = ->
        itemsSuccessFn = (data, status, headers, config) ->
            $scope.items = data.data
            return

        itemsErrorFn = (data, status, headers, config) ->
            Snackbar.error data.error
            return

        Items().all().then itemsSuccessFn, itemsErrorFn
        return

    $scope.items = []
    $scope.isAuthenticated = Authentication.isAuthenticated()
    activate()
    return
]
```

However, if you're using the `controllerAs` syntax, then you must keep the correct reference to `this` by using fat arrows. That way, you don't need a `vm` variable.

```
app.controller 'IndexController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'Items', 'Snackbar', ($scope, Authentication, Items, Snackbar) ->
    activate = =>
        itemsSuccessFn = (data, status, headers, config) =>
            @items = data.data
            return

        itemsErrorFn = (data, status, headers, config) ->
            Snackbar.error data.error
            return

        Items().all().then itemsSuccessFn, itemsErrorFn
        return

    @items = []
    @isAuthenticated = Authentication.isAuthenticated()
    activate()
    return
]
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that. However even when I've done what you've suggested, and try to `console.log @items` after activate, an array is still empty. It is also not rendering in the template giving an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` at the line `$scope.$watchCollection( -> $scope.items ) render` in the other `ItemsController`. What should I do now?

Comment: @Marcin can you add the new code you're having trouble with to the original question? It seems you are declaring the `watch` before creating `items`.